# Windows phone 7.1 app compatibility issues, VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, compatibility

So here's the story:

Back in 2013 I was developing apps in Windows Phone 7.1/8 platform, using Visual Studio 2012. After some point I had all my apps published and eventually stopped working on them; then I formatted my PC and only kept copies of my VS2012 "Projects" folder.

Last week I received an email from Microsoft that one of my apps will be unpublished from the Marketplace due to non-compliance with specific articles. That's fair enough, so I wanted to edit the app and re-submit, so that I avoid getting my app unpublished.

I installed Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 7 PC and copied the project folder into VS2015's "Projects". Then I tried to open the .sln file (which had been last edited back in 2014 in VS2012) and got a compatibility error, with the project and its files being listed as "unavailable" in the Solution Explorer.

I tried downloading VS2013 and installing that one instead, but I'm running Windows 7 and VS2013 won't install (requires later Windows version).

Has anyone of you faced a similar situation and if yes, how did you deal with it? I am desperate to create a new updated version of my app ASAP, as I don't want it to go off the Marketplace, but my hands are pretty much tied.

Thanks

Comment: What was the non-compliance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create or edit windows phone 7.1 projects in vs 2015.  The last version of visual studio you could use was vs 2012.  Here is a link to the windows phone 7.1 sdk which should install windows phone express

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570

and the update for windows phone 7.8

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36474

Comment: Thanks Ken, that's exactly what I was looking for. Accepting your answer for now, if I have any non-compliance issues again I will revert and seek more help.

Comment: Alright, took me that long to install it, as I have been caught up doing other stuff. Now I see that I can't actually launch VS2010 Express for WP, as it requires registration and the links to Microsoft's registration page are obsolete. Any workaround here? Many thanks